# How to extract specific elements from a nested list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list in Python, where each element is also a list. I would like to extract specific elements from this nested list based on certain conditions. For example, let's say I have the following nested list:

```py
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I want to extract all the elements at index 1 from each inner list, resulting in the output [2, 5, 8].

What would be an efficient way to achieve this in Python? Are there any built-in functions or methods that can help simplify this process? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Based on my attempt, I expected the extracted_elements list to contain the elements at index 1 from each inner list, which would be [2, 5, 8]. However, I'm not getting the desired output.

Could someone please point out what I might be doing wrong or suggest an alternative approach to successfully extract the specific elements from the nested list? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `print([inner[1] for inner in my_list])`

Comment: *"Could someone please point out what I might be doing wrong ..."* - You hare not doing anything at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily enough with a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
result = [sublist[1] for sublist in my_list]
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain why you used "result" variable instead of more meaningful naming?

Comment: You can use whatever name you like. I used `result` because this gives you the *result* you asked for. It's just an example - after all, I'm sure you wouldn't use the variable name `my_list` in production code either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy array https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> np_array = np.array(my_list)

>>>  np_array[:,1] # returns the second column
array([2, 5,8])`
```

Comment: It says: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: use : 'pip install numpy' to install it!

Comment: Numpy, though useful, is definitely overkill for this situation.

Comment: I know! the point was that manipulating 2D arrays is easily done with numpy. thanks for the advice